# I am not able to choose between windows 7 and ubuntu in the boot screen

Tags: 10.10

I first installed windows 7 in a partition. Then installed ubuntu in another partition. But i am not able to choose between those 2. It is directly going into windows 7. Please

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu using an USB drive? If so, GRUB may be installed in the USB rather than the hard drive. Try booting with the same USB drive plugged in, and edit the question with the results.

Answer (score 0):

You need Ubuntu 10.10 livecd for repairing grub boot loader . Here assuming the Ubuntu partition is sda7. Boot up ubuntu from the livecd,open terminal and run:

> sudo  fdisk -i

and see what is your linux partition and note it I assume it sda7 here.

> mount /dev/sda7 /mnt
>
> mount /dev/sda7 /mnt/boot
>
> grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sda
>
> mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
>
> mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
>
> mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
>
> chroot /mnt update-grub
>
> umount /mnt/sys
>
> sudo reboot